# Capybara::ElementNotFound - how do I see the source it checked against?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm using Capybara(v2.0.1) with RSpec(v2.11.0), and I have a spec very similar to the example on the [README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara):

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/dsl'

# other setup…

describe "Sign in" do
  include Capybara::DSL

  before do
    within("#session") do
      fill_in 'Login', :with => 'user@example.com'
      fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
    end
    click_link 'Sign in!'
  end

  subject { page }
  it { should have_content "logged_in? true" }
end
```

Unfortunately, this is the failure message I see:

> Failure/Error: within("#session") do
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find css "#session"

but it doesn't show me the output of the source it's used, and there's a redirect involved after that link is clicked so I'd like to be sure what's it's checking against.

It also seems that Capybara is suppressing warnings (which I find annoying, quite frankly) as I've tried `warn page.inspect` in several places and nothing in the output.

Would anyone be able to tell me how I can do this? Any help or insight given is much appreciated.

I should add I'm not using Rails or Cucumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

capybara's `save_and_open_page` writes the html to your app's tmp directory and opens it in your default browser.

it's mentioned in the [debugging section](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#debugging) of the section of capybara's readme these days.

Answer (score 4):

I just add this line at the start of my test:

```
puts "#{page.html.inspect}"
```

I have to look through it all on the command line, but it's quick and dirty.

Answer (score 1):

I use irb as a live debugger with Selenium so I can follow along as it goes. Pretty useful for debugging weirdness that goes on with Capybara/Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the entire source by using page.html.  From there it's pretty easy to inspect by checking for the first match of #session.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't see how I can inspect the source when I can't get anything to STDOUT from within an example block. Any idea why that would be? A before block does allow STDOUT, and this only happens when I use Capybara, Rack::Test doesn't give me this problem.

Comment: I see [someone else has the stdout problem too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402537/how-to-access-stdout-or-stderr-in-a-capybara-integration-test), so I've opened that part up to the Capybara mailing list. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you use the debugger gem and view it this way?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing that for running specs, it's so easy when all the output is already in the console, but I may use Pry. Thanks for all the help, it's much appreciated.